# Using SchemaExport in Play Framework

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

On Play Framework 1.2.5 with Jpa+Hibernate as ORM, I would like to call programmatically Hibernate tool SchemaExport.
I tried this code:

```
Ejb3Configuration cfg = getPlayEjb3Configuration();
Configuration configuration = cfg.getHibernateConfiguration();
try {
   SchemaExport se = new SchemaExport(configuration);
   se.setHaltOnError(true);
   se.setDelimiter(";").setFormat(true);
   se.execute(true, false, false, false);
}
catch(Exception e) {
 …
}
```

Where `getPlayEjb3Configuration()` is a "copy" of play framework `JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart()`.

I always obtain a `'no datasource provided'` exception message. 
I try to preserve configuration in a static reference (modifying play framework) without difference.

How can I obtain from play framework a correct Ejb3Configuration/HibernateConfiguration?
There's any alternative way to call SchemaExport?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on creating SchemaExport:

```
Connection connection = ...;
SchemaExport se = SchemaExport(configuration, connection);
```

And everything works.