# How can I get the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration in Play Framework 2 using the JPA plugin

Tags: hibernate, playframework-2.0

I can get the JPA Config like this:

```
Configuration jpaConf = Configuration.root().getConfig("jpa");
```

But how can I get the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration which I need to do a Schema Export like in this Question (base on Play Framework 1): [Using SchemaExport in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657762/using-schemaexport-in-play-framework)

My Play Framework 2.x application.conf has this:

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dpma"
db.default.user=bp
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

my persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="&quot;legalEntitiesTest&quot;"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="false"/>
        </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**For those unfamiliar with Play Framework: ** https://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.4/JavaJPA

Comment: What I really want to do is to be able to do a hibernate schema validation in my Global.java .  In order to do it, I need the Hibernate Configuration.  I need this because I want to use Evolutions, but still want to validate the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create hibernate configuration object yourself, using hibernate configuration file:

```
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.configure("path to hibernate config").getProperty("hibernate property");
```

If you do not use hibernate cfg file, you can instead add JPA entities to configuration this way (**it assums all your JPA classes belong to one package**):

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(EntityClass.class.getPackage().getName());
final Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
for (final Class<?> clazz : classes) {
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
}
```

Before you execute schema export, remember to set dialect:

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
```

Comment: please elaborate your snippet of Code. Code only answers like try this try that wont help anyone

Comment: @poornerd How do you configure your persistence provider?

Comment: @MonCalamari I just updated the description.  Have you used Play Framework before?